# Find a stolen iphone that isn't activated

Tags: iphone

I called Apple to see if they could ping my stolen iPhone 4. They said that they cant because the "find my iphone" isnt on. The phone isnt activated but the person who stole it has been using it to get into my emails, Facebook and other apps linked to my Apple ID, because as most know as long as there is wifi iPhones can used to do everytjing except make calls and text. 
Is there a way to find the location of the phone using the IMEI and the last time it was on wifi?

Answer (score 1):

Your carrier has a history of the approximate location of the phone based on the cell towers it connects to.

Get in touch with the police and they will in turn contact the carrier to get the info from them.

If the person connected the iPhone to their own Wi-Fi you can also ask the police to obtain the connection logs from your online services still configured on that phone (e-mail, Facebook, etc). With the IP address of the Wi-Fi connection it'll be very easy for them to track down the owner of that particular Internet connection.

Answer (score -1):

If the person has logged into your accounts, you may be able to contact the police to trace the IP address they have logged in from. That is, if your services you use provides ip history.

Comment: This has been downvoted without any explanation. I don't know by whom or why (shame on you!) but the answer is not a very practical solution. In practice it is *very* difficult to get providers to release this kind of information even when it is requested by law enforcement. And law enforcement aren't likely to go to the effort for a phone.

Comment: @symcbean the difficulty to get the info from providers by law enforcement *greatly* varies between countries, this is a really wild statement !